# Deploy warning SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near .. when publishing an SQL Server project

Tags: .net, sql-server, msbuild, publish

The project will build successfully, but will not publish.

Command:

```
msbuild /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="ENV.publish.xml" "MyDB.sqlproj"
```

Within the publish XML, I have configurations including: TargetDatabaseName, DeployScriptFileName, and TargetConnectionString.

The exact error when this command is run is:

```
MSSQL::-1121(252,40,252,40): Deploy warning SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near .. [C:\Solution\MyDB\MyDB.sqlproj]
```

In VS 2017 Pro, I can publish the project with the same configuration file without an issue.

The database project is based on SQL Server 2014.

Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework

The error occurs when the project is set to any .NET Framework version, including 4.5-4.8.

Comment: Check your SQL for instances of `..`. Perhaps missing a schema somewhere?

Comment: There are valid instances of `..` in some of the stored procedures, but there aren't any in the generated publish script.

Comment: Have you tried running the generated script in SQL Server Management Studio, it may get you closer to the issue?

Comment: I have to enable SQLCMD mode, but then it works. Note that it doesn't work even when there aren't any changes. The generated script simply checks for SQLCMD mode and then prints 'Update Complete'.

I am struggling to find what file to look in to find the .. that is causing the error. What does 1121(252,40,252,40) refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was difficult to find which DB object had the syntax error within Visual Studio.

I was able to figure it out by extracting a data-tier application within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The error logging was verbose and instead gave me the message: `Warning SQL 46010: Error validating element [dbo].[StoredProcedureCausingTheIssue]: Incorrect syntax near ..`